# How to correctly change text in delegate of listView?

Tags: qml, qtquick2

I'm a total QML noob so any ideas and thoughts would be helpful.

The idea is to do something similar to Microsoft To Do. I have a C++ model-bound ListView that inherits from QSqlQueryModel. There is a Delegate - Rectangle, inside of which there is a TextField. When you right-click on a list item, a menu is called up, in which there are "delete" and "edit" items.

The task is as follows: there is a whole list in which all names look like regular Label, that is, they are not changeable. When you click "edit" in the menu, the field becomes editable and the focus moves to it. After the change, from the change of focus / pressing the enter key, the new name is saved in the database, the model is updated and some more changes need to happen using the updated information from the model

I implemented this idea by having a textField in the delegate. When I click on "edit" in the menu, I set **readOnly** = false on the **TextField**, and I catch the change signal with **onEditingChange()**. The problem here is that after updating the model, apparently, the delegate and **textField** in which the **editingFinished** method is called is deleted and all further changes stumble over the error *ReferenceError:  is not defined.*

```
TextField {
    id: groupName

    readOnly: true
    selectByMouse: true
    anchors.fill:  parent
    anchors.margins: 8

    background: Rectangle{
        color: groupName.readOnly ? groupsDelegate.color : "white"
        radius: 8
    }

    text: groupsName
    font.bold: true
    font.pixelSize: 14

    onEditingFinished: {
        if(!readOnly){
            db.renameGroup(grModel.getId(index), text)
            readOnly = true;
            grModel.updateModel()
            tasksWidget.updateTasks(grModel.getId(index));
        }
    }
}
```

here, for example, it gives an error qrc:/main.qml:104: ReferenceError: tasksWidget is not defined. In any case, I get a lot of errors on the background of **onEditingFinished**(), I also had to do **readOnly = true**, because without this check, updateModel also called the **onEditingFinished**() signal.  I was already confused about all this. Can you please tell me how to implement this functionality?

I've been trying to figure all this out for the second day and, perhaps, the solution is somewhere on the surface, but I don't find it

Comment: What is tastWidgets? It is not defined in your example code? What is happening, when you comment out the taskWidgets.updateTasks() call?

Comment: In a clean design, I would expect any further update tasks be triggered by a signal from the model. So the updateTasks call should be obsolete.

Comment: For this kind of rug pulling model update I usually use [`callLater()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-qt.html#callLater-method-1) around the function that changes the model and triggers a rebuild of the delegates.

Comment: I ti s a bit difficult to assist you in a proper solution as there is information missing about what is `db`, `grModel` and `tasksWidget`. Maybe it can easily be solved by wrapping all those calls in one backend call, but I just don't know what this individual objects/calls are for. Assuming `grModel` is the model what is `db`? Why isn't `renameGroup` a function of the model which internally updates the model? And should the update to `taskWIdget` happen automatically due to an update of the model?